# Restrict Panning of d3.js chart to One Direction

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js

The [pannable & zoomable chart here](http://bl.ocks.org/mhsmith/5732011) allows panning in both X and Y directions. How can we restrict panning to only the horizontal direction? Zooming should still work in both directions just like the original.

Comment: Is this what you are loooking for http://jsfiddle.net/tmFSF/

Comment: @Nouphal.M Almost!! The zoom seems to change the scale of only the X axis. Can it zoom in both axes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep zooming in and out of the `y-axis` while restricting panning, you will end up with a rather weird user experience. Besides, by zooming in at one point and zooming out at another, the user will be able to *pan* the `y-axis` anyway.

You can do it, however, by changing the `yAxis` only if it is a *scale* event (i.e. `d3.event.scale` changes by `> 1e-5`).

Borrowing from @Nouphal.M's example: http://jsfiddle.net/tmFSF/1/

Note that the `y` scale still changes. Hence, if you redraw your chart, the position of the elements would still be different. To work around that, you might want to use a `y.copy()` as the `y` scale for the `zoom` behavior and manage the `domain` of the original `y` scale completely yourself in the `zoomed` function.